# geocoder.getFromLocationName error

Tags: java, android

Getting "always true" result on `if (location != null || !location.equals(""))` and when I search something like "sldjfuhsdhfj" it closes the app, but when I enter something like "Central Park" it works correctly.
What am I doing wrong?
Code I am using

```
public void onMapSearch(View view) {
    EditText locationSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    String location = locationSearch.getText().toString();
    List<Address> addressList = null;

    if (location != null || !location.equals("")) {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
        try {
            addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Address address = addressList.get(0);
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Marker"));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 16));
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Do something after 3s
                mMap.clear();
            }
        }, 3000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Address address = addressList.get(0)

You gave it junk so it is returning no results. addressList is empty. You are accessing the 0 element of something that is empty. You should have seen a message in the Android Monitor window of Android Studio that pointed you to this exact line / issue.